# I need urgent help for my ssd card

Tags: ssd

Hi everyone I urgently need all of your help!! my ssd card got damaged and corrupted and I have very important data on in it I'm not being able to fix can it fixed somehow? if so can anyone please tell the full details including all the steps by being specific about how can i repair it? its very important and urgent for me!! I'm really asking anybody my system is ubuntu 18.04  by the way I heard there is a way to recover deleted files from ssd card but can I still recover my data even without fixing the ssd card first? it's a yes and no question if you guys can message me back as soon as possible it will be great.

Comment: "please tell the full details including all the steps by being specific about how can i repair it?" take your computer and bring it to a professional. If it's indeed so important you don't want to risk causing more damage.

Comment: I already took our my ssd card and I did brought but he couldn't fix it any thoughts comments or questions?

Comment: also could you please give me your answer on my other as well when I said if its possible to still recover my data even if the ssd card is corrupted

Comment: So a professional has already seen it and couldn't solve, and you just left us know you've a broken SSD, honestly, why do you expect we can say more? Was that person expert in data recovery?

Comment: the person is only an I.T person also when I said my ssd card is damaged I didn't meant like its physically damaged or broken I only meant that its corrupted